# Spring STOMP - No matching message handler

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, sockets

My goal is to notify, if a player joins a team in real-time.
Since the player will be created in the controller, i want to notify the team about this change via socket.
This has been my first attempt in doing that:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/secure/players/")
public class PlayerController {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessageTemplate;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<PlayerDTO> createPlayer() {
        // ...
        // data is being processed
    
        // notify team about the change
        simpMessageTemplate.convertAndSend("/teams/" + selectedTeam.getId() + "/", player);


        return ...
    }
}
```

```java
@Controller
public class TeamSocket {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TeamSocket.class);

    @MessageMapping("/teams/{team}")
    @SendTo("/teams/{team}")
    public void teamEvent(@DestinationVariable String team) {
        logger.debug("Received message -> {}", team);
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        // I still dont fully understand this. Do i have to enable it? (It does not fix the issue).
        // config.enableSimpleBroker("/teams/");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/api/secure/stomp/").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

However, Spring tells me, that it was unable to map the request. What am i doing wrong?

```
DEBUG 29487 --- [nboundChannel-4] .WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler : Searching methods to handle SUBSCRIBE /teams/16 id=sub-0 session=0nkqv1km, lookupDestination='/teams/16'
DEBUG 29487 --- [nboundChannel-4] .WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler : No matching message handler methods.
DEBUG 29487 --- [nboundChannel-2] org.springframework.web.SimpLogging      : Processing SUBSCRIBE /teams/16 id=sub-0 session=0nkqv1km
```

```js
const client = new SockJS(`${REST_API}/api/secure/stomp/`);
const stompClient = Stomp.over(client);

stompClient.connect({}, (frame) => {
    stompClient.subscribe(`/teams/${teamId}`, (message) => {
        ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using path `"/teams/" + selectedTeam.getId() + "/"` in your convertAndSend method while you are subscribing to `/teams/${teamId}`. Do you need to add additional slash while subscribing or you may need to remove additional slash from convertAndSend?